# Angular UI Grid oData Support

Tags: javascript, rest, odata, angular-ui-grid

Is there any documentation/samples, about using Angular UI Grid with a OData/REST backend? Especially for paging/search functionality that would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third party feature out there, but I never had occasion to use it.

You can find the link on [this tutorial page](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/299_third_party_features), or just click [here](https://github.com/mirik123/ui-grid-odata)!

Comment: I had a look. Looks promising, but seems still to lack paging support. Unfortunately there seems to be no way to contact the developer on github?

Comment: The owner looks quite active, you could try adding an issue to that repository, or write your add-on on top of that and file a Pull Request